# Multiline Tab in EXT JS

Tags: extjs, multiline, sencha-architect, tabpanel

How to put the tabs in multiline for the ExtJs tabPanel
I tried with

```
<ext:TabPanel ID="tpnlApplication"          
runat="server"          
ActiveTabIndex="0"          
LayoutOnTabChange="true"          
EnableTabScroll="true"          
Plain="true"          
Border="true"          
Height="240">         
<Tabs>
```

Its not working